# How to Implement deeplinking in Xamarin Forms iOS using fallback method

Tags: javascript, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, deep-linking

I'm developing the `Xamarin.Forms` application. In that, we are having the support to resetting the password. For that, when clicking the forgot password button, I received my forgot password link via email. When user clicking that link, we have to navigate to our application if installed else to browser.

In `Android`, this behavior is working fine. We are using fallback method. Please refer the below code,

```
if(userAgentString.indexOf('Android')>0){

 window.location="intent://test.com/UV="+UVvalue+"&forgetuserId="+userID+"#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.test.tesApp;S.browser_fallback_url=https://test.com/index.html?UV="+UVvalue+";end"; 

 }
```

In `iOS`, I'm facing the error like in the screenshot below,

[Error message in the Safari browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqjIj.png)

We are using the below code,

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
  var UVvalue = getUrlVars()["UV"];
  var userID = getUrlVars()["forgetuserId"];
  var PortalValue=getUrlVars()["portal"]
  var isBrowserActive=true;
var userAgentString=navigator.userAgent;
var platform=navigator.platform;
  $('#lbl12').val(userAgentString);
var htmlelement="<label>"+userAgentString+"</label>";
var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body');


window.setTimeout(function(){
if(isBrowserActive==true && userAgentString.indexOf('iPhone')>1){
window.location.href="https://test.com/index.html?UV="+UVvalue;
}
},3500);


if(platform=="Win32" || platform=="Macintel"){
$('#imgLoader').css({'margin-top':'9%'});
window.location.href="https://test.com/index.cfm?mg=CI.ResetforgetPassword&UV="+UVvalue+"&portal="+PortalValue;
}
 function windowClose() {
window.open('','_parent','');
window.close();
}
$(window).blur(function(){
console.log('Window blurred');
isBrowserActive=false; 
if(platform!="Win32" || platform!="Macintel"){

}
window.clearTimeout();
//windowClose();

});
if (userAgentString.indexOf('iPhone')>0){

$('#imgLoader').css({'margin-top':'53%'})
window.location.href="testApp://testApp?UV="+UVvalue+"&forgetuserId="+userID;

}
else if(userAgentString.indexOf('Android')>0){

 window.location="intent://test.com/UV="+UVvalue+"&forgetuserId="+userID+"#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.test.tesApp;S.browser_fallback_url=https://test.com/index.html?UV="+UVvalue+";end"; 

 }
```

Comment: This is a known issue which caused by many reasons ,for example the url or network environmrnt is unsafe... So firstly you could clean the cache of Safari . `Setting -> Safari -> Clear History and Website Data`  . And the best solution is that you should the new web page in WebView in your app .

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT i follow above steps, but no help

Comment: You could open the new page with  WebView in your project .